# vuejs bootstrap card component animation

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-animations, vue-component

I have a users array and in loop show each user in card component, I want when clicked on card expand that card with animation to full width for showing of user details and hide other cards, [my code on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppYPRy)
My problem is with animation, how do I hide smoothly other card and expand the clicked card to the whole row (col-12).

```js
Vue.component('card', {
  props: ['user','index'],
  template:`
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card step">
        <div class="card-body p-3 clearfix" @click="view(index)">
            name: {{ user.name }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`,
  methods: {
    view(index) {
      this.$emit('on-view', index);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users:[{name:'john',
           description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'},
           {name:'mike',
           description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'},
           {name:'kevin',
           description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'},
           {name:'david',
           description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'},
          {name:'sasha',
           description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.'}],
    detailMode: false
  },
  methods: {
    onDetailMode(index) {
      console.log(index);
      this.detailMode = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <card :user="user" :index="index"
          v-for="(user,index) in users"
          @on-view="onDetailMode"></card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data in your main component:

```
data: {
    selectedUser: null,
    user: [...]
}
methods: {
   select (id) {
       this.selectedUser = id;
   }
}
```

In you component add a property:

```
Vue.component('card', {
   props: ['user','index', 'details'],
   template:`
   <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 mb-3">
    <div class="card step">
      <div class="card-body p-3 clearfix" @click="view(index)">
          name: {{ user.name }}
       </div>
      <div v-show="details"> ... </div>
    </div> 
  </div>`,
 }
});
```

Then in the loop you can add the appropriate behavior.

```
<div v-for="item in users" @click="selectedUser = item.id">
    <card :details="item.id === selectedUser"></card>
</div>
```